# Dispenser tower defense

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minecraft server with a tower defense on it and I need to know how to make dispensers fire automatically without showing any redstone. I also want the dispenser to **MOVE UP** and have a block to be placed under it. I want to use only commands and redstone. I'm playing MC version 1.9.2

Comment: indirectly power the dispenser?

Comment: The bold doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use commandblock clock, placing redstone block adjacent to dispenser, then second commandblock in chain will revert that block to another solid block - for example stone. Use some kind of fast clock for that and you are done.

For players there will be always stone visible, because redstone block will change so fast. But dispenser will fire.

If it is not fast enough for you, you can mask it with something around it. Also be aware that a lot of those will have performance hit to the server.

Comment: or he could simply `/summon` arrows in the direction the dispenser is facing. (motion tag)

Comment: I need the dispenser to move UP though

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want any blocks or redstone to be seen, use a /clone command to move the dispenser, and a /setblock to place a redstone block near it then another one to replace that block with air